# Hear myself in headset during call?

Tags: audio, calls, phone-app, android-10, samsung-galaxy-note-9

I have this issue when using earbuds. When I talk on the phone, since the buds are plugged into my ears, I can't hear my own voice and I find myself shouting.

Is there a way to configure Android so that I can hear my own voice thru the headset?

I'm on a Samsung Galaxy Note 9, with Android 10.

Comment: I doubt it, and you wouldn't want it anyway. Hearing your own voice as an echo in the phone is very annoying for most people. Simply remember to not scream... Most people manage it these days.